# How to run npm start without the terminal?

Tags: node.js, npm, ethereum

I have a Ether Explorer. I have made a native app of it using "npm-nativefier".
The problem is that every time i run the application, i have to start my private "geth" network and "npm-start" in the project directory using CMD to make the application work.
running geth is not a problem as of now.

Is there a way so that i don't have to do the npm start? 
running a script or something like that.

It should start automatically when i run the explorer. Given that my geth is already running.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No idea about Ether explorer, but why not make a batch file that simply runs both commands?

Comment: @AluanHaddad that was a good idea and it worked fine. but now i need to run the batch file first and then open my explorer. Can you please tell me something such that i open my explorer and the batch file runs before the startup of my explorer/app.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe  you are looking for something like this. [auto-launch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-launch)

I also have no idea what Ether Explorer is, but maybe the above will help.

Comment: no, not exactly this.
i want something that i can add to the code of my app, such that when i open my app/explorer, it will automatically run npm-start before opening the app.

Comment: @JohnMichael try this then... it also contains an API and should answer what you need if I understand it correctly. [node-autostart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-autostart). If not you will need to actually get something that can run a linux or windows command from inside the program. (There are a few in NPM)

Comment: Okay.. can you tell me how can i use it in my code? i tried using it in my app.js but it doesn't work.